# Ошибка компиляции Android проекта (проблема с JDK)

Tags: android, unity3d, java

Не могу понять в чем дело и что именно оно от меня хочет ¯_(ツ)_/¯
Вот собственно копипаст всего текста ошибки прямиком из Юнити. Если нужно предоставить еще что то для того, что бы решить проблему напишите пожалуйста. Установлен новейший SDK и JDK. NDK не устанавливал.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
E:/Android/JDK\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:/Android/AndroidSDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "E:\Unity3D\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
    at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Что пытался предпринять для решения проблемы (ошибку не понял, по этому действовал наугад):

1. Переустановил Джаву.
2. Выделил больше памяти под нее.
3. Накачал больше версий SDK под все версии Андроида.

Comment: Какие то плагины? А пустой проект билдит?

Comment: К сожалению пустой проект тоже не копилится. Плагинов не устанавливал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что не находится класс `sun/misc/BASE64Encoder`

Это насколько я помню результат какой-то патентной войны между Oracle и кем то еще, в общем если не вдаваться в тонкости, замените

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
```

на

```
import java.util.Base64
```

или

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

[Подробнее здесь](https://www.mkyong.com/java/access-restriction-the-type-base64encoder-is-not-accessible-due-to-restriction/)

**Update**

Как вариант, если Unity тянет этот класс откуда то из своих кишок, то переходите либо на Java 8 или даже Java 7

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую применить Ваш совет :)

Comment: Не забудьте, пожалуйста, ответить, помогло или нет.

Comment: Немного порывшись, не понял где именно надо менять эти строки, так как Java в своем проекте не использую вообще. А тут, насколько я понял, решение для кода на Java.

Comment: Я так и понял, что тянется из кишков Unity. Это я и предполагал в апдейте ответа в Java < 9 такой проблемы нет

Answer (score 1):

Помогла установка JDK более ранней версии (в данном случае JDK 8.161, была 9+) + установил Java той же версии. Спасибо всем кто участвовал в решении данного вопроса.